# Compress image size on upload -PHP

Tags: php, image

I am uploading screenshots to my website.
I want to upload the original image with same properties in width and height only i want to reduce its size,for example if the image size before uploading is 3 MB then after uploading/saving it must be 300 KB But in my case image is generated with no display completely blank image.

Below is the code I'm using to upload my files..

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="something" class="uniForm">
    <input name="new_image" id="new_image" size="30" type="file" class="fileUpload" />
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="submitButton">Upload/Resize Image</button>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      if (isset ($_FILES['new_image'])){
          $imagename = $_FILES['new_image']['name'];
          $source = $_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'];
          $target = "images/".$imagename;
          move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

          $imagepath = $imagename;
          $save = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
          $file = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

          list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 


          $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height) ; 
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
          imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height) ; 

          imagejpeg($tn, $save, 70) ; 

          $save = "images/sml_" . $imagepath; //This is the new file you saving
          $file = "images/" . $imagepath; //This is the original file

          list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 

          $modwidth = 130; 

          $diff = $width / $modwidth;

          $modheight = 185; 
          $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
          imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 

          imagejpeg($tn, $save, 70) ; 
        echo "Large image: <img src='images/".$imagepath."'><br>"; 
        echo "Thumbnail: <img src='images/sml_".$imagepath."'>"; 

      }
    } ?>
```

it is working fine if i upload jpg image /but not working for others 
i want to use it for every image type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For type detection use the below code and explanation.

```
<?php
function imageCreateFromAny($filepath) {
    $type = exif_imagetype($filepath); // [] if you don't have exif you could use getImageSize()
    $allowedTypes = array(
        1,  // [] gif
        2,  // [] jpg
        3,  // [] png
        6   // [] bmp
    );
    if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case 1 :
            $im = imageCreateFromGif($filepath);
        break;
        case 2 :
            $im = imageCreateFromJpeg($filepath);
        break;
        case 3 :
            $im = imageCreateFromPng($filepath);
        break;
        case 6 :
            $im = imageCreateFromBmp($filepath);
        break;
    }   
    return $im; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This may not be the answer

//in php we have different functions for different image formats so this may helps you
imagecreatefromjpeg ( string $filename )
imagecreatefrompng ( string $filename )
imagecreatefromgif ( string $filename )
```

[imagecreatefromjpeg DOC](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg)

[imagecreatefrompng DOC](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefrompng)

[imagecreatefromgif DOC](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromgif)

Comment: thanks bro 
i knw them
i have already used 1 and i really dont knw how to use for detecting the type if the source is png or other so that we can query accordingly